# Is there any way to get data by column in jpa spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

This is my controller code

```
@GetMapping("/customerWasteRequest/{customer}")
public List<CustomerWasteRequest> getCustomerWasteRequest(@PathVariable String customer) {
    return service.fetchWasteRequestByCustomer(customer);
}
```

This is my service code

```
public class CustomerWasteRequestService{
    @Autowired

    private CustomerWasteRequestRepository repo;

    public List<CustomerWasteRequest> fetchWasteRequestByCustomer(String customer) {
                return repo.findByCustomer(customer);
    }
}
```

Repository code

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerWasteRequestRepository extends JpaRepository<CustomerWasteRequest, Integer> {

    public List<CustomerWasteRequest> findByCustomer(String customer);
}
```

when I called the function  - getCustomerWasteRequests

```
private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/customerWasteRequest';

 getCustomerWasteRequests(customer:string) : Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/${customer}`);  
  }
```

It gives me the error

{"cause":{"cause":null,"message":"For input string: "newcustomer""},"message":"Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value 'newcustomer'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "newcustomer""}

in   http://localhost:8080/customerWasteRequests/newcustomer

Comment: Can you post the model class, i.e., `CustomerWasteRequest`?

Comment: export class WasteRequest {

    id:number;
    wasteType:string;
    quantity: number;
    date: Date;
    customer: string;

    constructor(){}
}

Comment: This model appears to be based off TypeScript. What about the model at backend? Is the attribute `customer` an `integer` or a `String` ?

Answer (score 0):

> "Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value 'newcustomer'

Does your property `customer` into Entity `CustomerWasteRequest` has a Type `Integer` instead of `String`?

Comment: Yes there was a type integer instead of string.Thank you so much for showing the error